# echo tells me my env vars are defined, but docker-compose tells me "variable is not set". How do I pass them to docker-compose?

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm using Docker v19.03.13 .  In my shell, I have defined some env vars ...

```
davea$ echo $AZ_SQL_TP_SRVR
localhost
davea$ echo $AZ_SQL_TP_DB
myDB
```

I would like to refrence these in my docker-compose.yml file, which is below ...

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  sqlserver-db:
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        - AZ_SQL_TP_SRVR=${AZ_SQL_TP_SRVR}
        - AZ_SQL_TP_PORT=1433
        - AZ_SQL_TP_DB=${AZ_SQL_TP_DB}
        - AZ_SQL_TP_USERNAME=${AZ_SQL_TP_USERNAME}
        - AZ_SQL_TP_PASSWORD=${AZ_SQL_TP_PASSWORD}
    container_name: sqlserver-db
    ports:
      - ${AZ_SQL_TP_PORT}:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=${AZ_SQL_TP_PASSWORD}
      - TZ=${TZ}
    volumes:
      - ../../mydb/mypb:/sqlscripts
    tty: true
    command: /bin/bash entrypoint.sh
```

but when I run my docker instance, I get these warnings complaining about not being able to find the vars ...

```
davea$ docker-compose up -d
WARNING: The AZ_SQL_TP_SRVR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The AZ_SQL_TP_DB variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

What else do I need to do to make my docker-compose file recognize my env vars defined in my shell?

Comment: No idea about docker, but if it's running in a new subshell it might not find the env variables. In that case exporting the variables so that the sub-shells also have access to the variables might help.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the comments mentioned, you did assign with `AZ_SQL_TP_DB=myDB`, this is not enough.

You could choose either of next to made it work.

- Option 1

  ```
  $ export AZ_SQL_TP_DB=myDB
  $ docker-compose up -d
  ```
- Option 2

  ```
  $ AZ_SQL_TP_DB=myDB docker-compose up -d
  ```

Or add `.env` file in the same folder of `docker-compose.yaml` with next contents:

```
$ cat .env
AZ_SQL_TP_SRVR=localhost
AZ_SQL_TP_DB=myDB
$ docker-compose up -d
```